# Open server again after closing

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm using HTTP Node.js.

To prevent new sessions while I already have an active one I use server.close();.
When this active session is finished I would like to open the server for new sessions again. Ex server.open();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  server.close();
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.end(function() {
      server.listen(3000);
    });
  }, 5000);
}).listen(3000);
```

(where `setTimeout` emulates some operation that may take some time)

However, I think that notifying clients that they have to wait a while is a better solution than just closing the server altogether:

```
var http   = require('http');
var busy   = false;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (busy) {
    res.writeHead(503);
    return res.end();
  }
  busy = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.end(function() {
      busy = false;
    });
  }, 5000);
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: But how would I do to open it again for new sessions once the time has run out?

Comment: That's why there's a `server.listen()` in the `res.end()` handler: it will make the server listen for new incoming requests again.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback from `server.close()` to run `server.listen()`, like this:

```
server.close(function() { 
    server.listen(8080);
})
```